# How to launch browser without setting local driver in selenium? (Without accessing local chromeDriver.exe)

Tags: java, selenium

```
public MainActionFlow() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://ChromeDriver_test//chromedriver.exe");
    driverForTesting = new ChromeDriver();
    this.driverForTesting.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

is there any way that we can launch browser without local drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used below code,  it downloads driver in runtime and accesses the drivers
[image]
Pom.xml
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is- downloading all the driver executables automatically ?
If so, yes its possible by using BoniGarcia's Webdrivermanager. WebDriverManager  helps to download binanries/executables in an automated way. It supports browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, Opera, PhantomJS, Microsoft Edge, or Internet Explorer.

We just need to add its dependency through Maven or Gradle to download all the necessary drivers. It will download ONLY if they are not present on the WebDriverManager cache (~/.m2/repository/webDriver by default).

Add following dependency in your POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Once this is done you can instantiate your driver session by just below line -

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

visit this page for more details-
https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

Answer (score 0):

You should have some webdriver running at remote computer. Then You do somehting like this:

```java
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://www.example.com"), chromeOptions);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
driver.quit();
```

Where `http://www.example.com` is the URL your remote web driver is accessible with.

See the details [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/remote_webdriver/remote_webdriver_client/).